# about " should have to "

Tags: meaning

> It's not right that he should have to ride the lightning.

I found this expression in the story of *"Ride the Lightning"*.

I think it is okay to use "should ride" or "have to ride" instead of "should have to ride" because "should and have to" have same meaning like "must " or "obligation", and using "should" and "have to, which equals must" at the same time is a kind of duplication.

> 1. He should ride that
> 2. He has to ride that
> 3. He should have to ride that

What is the difference in meaning between 3 and others.

Does 3 have stronger meaning than others ?

Comment: I'd not choose 'should ride' here, as the alternative sense (not involving necessity) would correctly be inferred. You need to understand that the modals are very polysemous (have many senses). Have a look under the relevant postings here. And do you mean 'It's not right that he have to ride the lightning.' or 'It's not right that he has to ride the lightning.' ?

Comment: You mean 'sholud ride' can have other meanings and by using 'should have to' the meaning  of obligation in the above sentence  can become certain ? Am I on the right way ?  And concerning your question, I mean the latter. I've learned 'have to or has to' equals 'must' of obligation. So I think ' he has to ride that' equals 'he must ride that'.